# proxy behind traefik ssl cert

Tags: ssl, traefik, http-proxy

I have a nodejs http-proxy behind traefik. Problem is, teh traefik cert is use instead of the website cert.

I need

CLIENT ----------> TRAEFIK -------> PROXY (nodejs http-proxy) -----> https://google.fr

Is this possible to keep the google cert between CLIENT and GOOGLE as a proxy/vpn does? Do you have some documention I could read about my issue?

I don't want to install an auto signed cert on every computer that use that service.